# How to rename field in generated Java class to prevent problems with Java compiler

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have to use a published (3rd party) protocol buffer (*.proto*) file which  contains the field with name from the [*Java reserved keywords list*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). So I can't change names it this file. As the result after compiling (via *protoc*) protocol buffer in to the *Java* code I get the class that can not be compiled with *Java*.

The message I have to parse was generated with the original field's name (non valid in *Java*) with help of *C*, for example.

As I understand, I can not change the generated code without having troubles during using this message/class.

How can I change the name of generated field (use some mapping rules during running *protoc* or use annotations) in generated *Java* class safely?

The sample.

The *proto* file:

```
package sample.wrongname.protobuf;

enum SomeType {
    cool_name = 1;
    another_cool_name = 2;
    native = 3;
}
```

Generated *Java* class:

```
public final class Sample {
  private Sample() {}
  public static void registerAllExtensions(
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
  }
  /**
   * Protobuf enum {@code sample.wrongname.protobuf.SomeType}
   */
  public enum SomeType
      implements com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum {
    /**
     * <code>cool_name = 1;</code>
     */
    cool_name(0, 1),
    /**
     * <code>another_cool_name = 2;</code>
     */
    another_cool_name(1, 2),
    /**
     * <code>native = 3;</code>
     */
    native(2, 3),
    ;

    /**
     * <code>cool_name = 1;</code>
     */
    public static final int cool_name_VALUE = 1;
    /**
     * <code>another_cool_name = 2;</code>
     */
    public static final int another_cool_name_VALUE = 2;
    /**
     * <code>native = 3;</code>
     */
    public static final int native_VALUE = 3;


    public final int getNumber() { return value; }

    public static SomeType valueOf(int value) {
      switch (value) {
        case 1: return cool_name;
        case 2: return another_cool_name;
        case 3: return native;
        default: return null;
      }
    }

    public static com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<SomeType>
        internalGetValueMap() {
      return internalValueMap;
    }
    private static com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<SomeType>
        internalValueMap =
          new com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<SomeType>() {
            public SomeType findValueByNumber(int number) {
              return SomeType.valueOf(number);
            }
          };

    public final com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.EnumValueDescriptor
        getValueDescriptor() {
      return getDescriptor().getValues().get(index);
    }
    public final com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.EnumDescriptor
        getDescriptorForType() {
      return getDescriptor();
    }
    public static final com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.EnumDescriptor
        getDescriptor() {
      return Sample.getDescriptor().getEnumTypes().get(0);
    }

    private static final SomeType[] VALUES = values();

    public static SomeType valueOf(
        com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.EnumValueDescriptor desc) {
      if (desc.getType() != getDescriptor()) {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
          "EnumValueDescriptor is not for this type.");
      }
      return VALUES[desc.getIndex()];
    }

    private final int index;
    private final int value;

    private SomeType(int index, int value) {
      this.index = index;
      this.value = value;
    }

    // @@protoc_insertion_point(enum_scope:sample.wrongname.protobuf.SomeType)
  }


  public static com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor
      getDescriptor() {
    return descriptor;
  }
  private static com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor
      descriptor;
  static {
    java.lang.String[] descriptorData = {
      "\n\014sample.proto\022\031sample.wrongname.protobu" +
      "f*<\n\010SomeType\022\r\n\tcool_name\020\001\022\025\n\021another_" +
      "cool_name\020\002\022\n\n\006native\020\003"
    };
    com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.InternalDescriptorAssigner assigner =
        new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.    InternalDescriptorAssigner() {
          public com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry assignDescriptors(
              com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor root) {
            descriptor = root;
            return null;
          }
        };
    com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor
      .internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(descriptorData,
        new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {
        }, assigner);
  }

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(outer_class_scope)
}
```

Comment: Rename `native(2, 3)` to a valid Java method name `nativeFoo(2, 3)`. As long you don't change the structure of the protobuffer there is no problem.

Comment: I posted a small example for demonstration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small example.

Protobuffer using a Java reserved keyword.

```
package wrong.name;
option java_outer_classname = "WrongProtos";
message Foo {
    required SomeType id = 1;
}
enum SomeType {
    cool_name = 1;
    another_cool_name = 2;
    native = 3;
}
```

Protobuffer using the same structure but a different name instead.

```
package right.name;
option java_outer_classname = "RightProtos";
message Foo {
    required SomeType id = 1;
}
enum SomeType {
    cool_name = 1;
    another_cool_name = 2;
    different = 3;
}
```

Compile the protobuffer

```
protoc --java_out=src/ *.proto
```

Rename in `WrongProtos.java`

```
native(2, 3)  -->  nativeFoo(2, 3)
case 3: return native;  -->  case 3: return nativeFoo;
```

Small snippet to show that the structure can be read with both protobuff definitions.

```
WrongProtos.Foo.Builder outFoo = WrongProtos.Foo.newBuilder();
outFoo.setId(WrongProtos.SomeType.nativeFoo);
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/proto.bin")) {
    outFoo.build().writeTo(output);
}
System.out.printf("outFoo number: %d  name: %s%n",
        outFoo.getId().getNumber(), outFoo.getId());

RightProtos.Foo inFoo = RightProtos.Foo.parseFrom(
        new FileInputStream("/tmp/proto.bin"));
System.out.printf("inFoo number: %d  name: %s%n",
        inFoo.getId().getNumber(), inFoo.getId());
}
```

output

```
outFoo number: 3  name: nativeFoo
inFoo number: 3  name: different
```

The output shows that only in case you access the field name itself there would be a difference. In the binary data the field name is not stored.

**edit** Another way could be to rename the field into uppercase `native --> NATIVE`.